# Why was iswitchb removed from GNU Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs

I have used IswitchB for a number of years, but in version 24 of Emacs, it has been removed. My muscle memory is finding the transition to Icomplete or Ido difficult.

I know that it's possible, at least for now, to download `iswitchb` separately and get it to work with Emacs 24. But before I do that: **why was `iswitchb` removed from Emacs?** Will I be doing myself a disservice if I continue to use `iswitchb`?

Comment: Hm. I'm on 24.3.1, and `iswitchb-mode` was included by default. You sure it's not just disabled? Check what `M-x customize-option iswitchb-mode` and if changing it gives you the mode back.

Comment: Looks like it was just moved to `lisp/obsolete`. That happened on 2014-02-06.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IswitchB has not been removed.  You can continue to use it, with no problem.  It is considered by Emacs Dev to be obsolete, and Icomplete is its suggested replacement.

This action was taken because [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) felt that Icomplete had been sufficiently enhanced that it can now do what IswitchB does. You might agree or disagree, but as far as I know that was the reasoning.

Comment: Found the commit, and it pointed to [the relevant mailing list thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2013-11/msg00501.html).